# How do I remove a history entry in GreaseMonkey?

Tags: greasemonkey, browser-history

Similar to [Change the URL using GreaseMonkey](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38543998/change-the-url-using-greasemonkey)

I have an internal URL that shows a form which I have to press a button to trigger a `POST` on the same URL with extra data.  What happens is the landing URL and the result of the `POST` gives two different history entries.

I have my GreaseMonkey script already clicking the button, but what I want is if I press back it goes two history entries back, rather than the `GET` page which then triggers my GreaseMonkey script again.

Comment: Hm looking at [the current History API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History), I'm not sure if this is possible. The browser's back&forth history buttons aren't something you can tamper with either. You could probably easily write a userscript to add a button that goes back two history entries. You could maybe overwrite the form's submit button to instead send the form via the Fetch API and then use `window.history.replaceState` to do some monkey business there, but I'm not sure.

Comment: yes the answer being no.